# Will routers "short circuit" their own external ip address?

Tags: networking, router, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connecting to my own network via external IP](https://superuser.com/questions/396111/connecting-to-my-own-network-via-external-ip)

If I can access my router home page (or ssh etc.) through LAN machines via 0.0.0.1 and from anywhere on the internet via 0.0.0.2, and I type each of these into a browser on a machine within the LAN, will the router treat these requests differently?

For example, will the router realise that the external IP maps to the router itself and therefore treat it as if I had just typed in the internal IP instead?

Or will it depend on the router?

Comment: What?!  That makes no sense. The lowest private ip range is 10.0.0.x.  Have you managed to set machines to  0.0.0.x? See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918 to see private ip ranges

Comment: How your router handles this sort of thing is a function of the particular router & configuration. I've had routers handle this sort of thing in differing ways. You should indicate what router hardware/software you're using.

Comment: I think those were supposed to be sample IP Addresses where 0.0.0.1 is the internal ip address and 0.0.0.2 is the external ip address. At least I hope that is what was meant.

Comment: Sorry yes those are sample IP addresses, not real ones. Didn't want to publicise my actual setup.

Comment: This question is not the same as the one it is marked a duplicate of - this question asks about accessing the router itself, while the duplicate asks about accessing a machine behind the router, which from the outside will involve DNAT, while from the inside for it to work would have to involve DNAT and SNAT.  NAT likely has little to do with the scenario here.

Answer (score 1):

The lowest private ip range is 10.0.0.x.  Have you managed to set machines to  0.0.0.x? See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918 to see private ip ranges

The IP you'd use from within your LAN is different to the one you'd use from outside your LAN.

But i've heard that there are some routers that when you're inside your LAN, you can use the external IP.  Maybe they work by redirecting to the local one. I don't know more about that function, hopefully somebody else does.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question depends on the router. Some routers utilize **NAT reflection** by default and will route you to their WAN IP just fine from one of the LAN IPs, though some routers do require that you enable that setting in the config, but some routers just won't do it at all.

Answer (score 0):

My router does not - and I like it that way, because it allows me to test firewall settings and port forwarding by making requests to my own external IP address.  I'm using a NETGEAR WNR3500L-100NAS, flashed with DD-WRT.

I would assume that any router would send an external request outside the network, unless it's been specifically configured to rewrite packet requests to a certain IP (your external IP).